# Find the coefficient of ${x^9}$ in the expansion of $ (1 + x)( 1 + x^2)( 1 + x^3)..(1 + x^{100})$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Find the coefficient of ${x^9}$ in the expansion of $\left( {1 + x} \right)\left( {1 + {x^2}} \right)\left( {1 + {x^3}} \right)..\left( {1 + {x^{100}}} \right)$.
The official answer is **8**.

How do I find the general term,

Dividing the above equation by $(1-x)$ is not generating the required result.

Comment: Expanding the product will result in $2^{100}$ terms of the form $x^k$. You want to count how many of them are $x^9$.

Comment: isnt this an IIt JEE question if i am not mistaken?

Comment: Yes this is IIT JEE Question

Comment: I'm really not sure but I doubt if we could use partition of integer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\begin{align}9=9+0\\=8+1\\=7+2\\=6+3\\=6+2+1\\=5+4\\=5+3+1\\=4+3+2\end{align}$$

We don't have to worry about 4 summands, since $1+2+3+4>9$. There is no known closed form for the [general term](https://oeis.org/A000009).

Answer (score 5):

An "x^9" occurs in this expression exactly when a sequence of powers of $x$s add up to a total exponent of $9$. For instance, the first and eighth terms contribute $x$ and $x^8$, for a total of $x^9$ (where in all other terms you multiply by $1$).

The sequences we care about

- start at 1
- are increasing
- Have no two exponents the same

So now you can just start writing them down:

```
9
1,8
2,7
3,6
4,5
1,2,6
1,3,5
2,3,4
```

...
and there are eight of those.